# How to read a data.txt text fil, sort the data and then convert it into DataFrame using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-files, txt

I have a textfile (.txt) which contains data and it shows like this:-

```
Yield: 99.7598
Timestamp: 2021/February/13-01:55:04
Angle: 0.00309331
ErrorCode 10: 6
ErrorCode 12: 2
```

and now I want to convert it into Data Frame using the python pandas like the one below: -

**FileName  |  Yield  | TimeStamp   | Angle    | ErrorCode 10    | ErrorCode 12**

```
xxxxx     99.75 2021/Feb      0.003      6                2
```

I tried to write this code by doing this: -

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def sortbycode():
    sam_file = open('210107343_summary.txt', 'r')
    sams = []
    for line in sam_file:
        sams.append([i for i in line.strip("\n").split(":")])
    sams.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
    for sam in sams:
        print("{0:5}|{1:13}".format(*sam))
sortbycode()
```

This is the output I am getting at the moment:-

Output:

```
Angle| 0.00309331  
ErrorCode 10| 6           
ErrorCode 12| 2           
Timestamp| 2021/February/13-01
Yield| 99.7598
```

Which is no good because my plan was to build that and convert it into dataframe. I am stuck at this bit for converting it into Dataframe. There is an another thing about this output, it is missing the filename too.

Can you please help me fix this mistake or show me the direction to correct way?

Comment: Does every file have these exact five key-value pairs? Or you may have more than five lines in one file?

Comment: I suppose you have more than one record ? is there only 1 record per file, like the example ? or one file can have several records ? if it is the case, please show us.

Comment: It's only 1 record per file and we have hundred of files. We have more than 5 five lines and that would be ErrorCode 10,12,13 and 20 that's it. Our result files will only show the fails for each errorcode and if it has no fails for this specific errorcodem it will not be included. That's how our production tool works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer:

As the OP mentioned that there are text files with one record only, the following solution is the proper one:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
from os import sep, getcwd
from path import glob, Path
from collections import OrderedDict

def oneFileSingleRecordParser(textFilePath):
    fileName = textFilePath.rsplit(sep, 1)[-1]
    
    with open(textFilePath, "r") as textFile:
        # The structure is:
        # Yield:
        # Timestamp
        # Angle
        # ErrorCode 10
        # ErrorCode 12
        # ErrorCode 16
        # ErrorCode 20
        
        # The error codes can be present or absent
        lines = textFile.readlines()
        
        dataDict = OrderedDict()
        dataDict["File Name"] = fileName
        
        for line in lines:
            matchObject = re.match(r"(\w+\s?\d*):\s(.*)", line.strip())
            
            if matchObject is not None:
                key, value = matchObject.groups()
                dataDict[key] = value
            
        return dict(dataDict)

def convertAllFilesToDataFrame(textFilePathsRoot, parser = oneFileSingleRecordParser):
    if not os.path.isdir(textFilePathsRoot):
        raise Exception("Please pass in a valid path to the root of the text files")

    textFilePaths = list(map(lambda path: str(path), Path(textFilePathsRoot).glob("*.txt")))
    
    dataDicts = []
    
    for textFilePath in textFilePaths:
        dataDicts.append(parser(textFilePath))
    
    dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(dataDicts)
    return dataFrame
```

`convertAllFilesToDataFrame("path/to/your/text/file/directory")` should still produce the following output (in my case i only have two files with the exact same record):

[image]

### Original Answer

The problem can be tackled in two ways depending on the structure of the text files:

- A single text file contains exactly five lines (a single record)
- A single text file may contain multiples of 5 lines (multiple records)

Here's my take which tackles both ways:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
from os import sep, getcwd
from path import glob, Path
from collections import OrderedDict

def oneFileSingleRecordParser(textFilePath):
    fileName = textFilePath.rsplit(sep, 1)[-1]
    
    with open(textFilePath, "r") as textFile:
        # The structure is:
        # Yield:
        # Timestamp
        # Angle
        # ErrorCode 10
        # ErrorCode 12
        lines = textFile.readlines()
        
        if len(lines) != 5:
            raise Exception("The file at {} doesn't have a proper single record.".format(textFilePath))
        
        dataDict = OrderedDict()
        dataDict["File Name"] = fileName
        
        for line in lines:
            # regex to extract the key and value name
            matchObject = re.match(r"(\w+\s?\d*):\s(.*)", line.strip())
            
            if matchObject is not None:
                key, value = matchObject.groups()
                dataDict[key] = value
            
        return dict(dataDict)

def oneFileMultiRecordParser(textFilePath):
    fileName = textFilePath.rsplit(sep, 1)[-1]
    
    with open(textFilePath, "r") as textFile:
        # The structure is:
        # Yield_1:
        # Timestamp_1:
        # Angle_1:
        # ErrorCode 10_1:
        # ErrorCode 12_1:
        # Yield_2:
        # Timestamp_2:
        # Angle_2:
        # ErrorCode 10_2:
        # ErrorCode 12_2:
        # ...
        lines = textFile.readlines()
        
        if len(lines) % 5 != 0:
            raise Exception("The file at {} doesn't have a uniform structure.".format(textFilePath))
        
        records = []
        
        dataDict = OrderedDict()
        dataDict["File Name"] = fileName
        
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            # regex to extract the key and value name
            matchObject = re.match(r"(\w+\s?\d*):\s(.*)", line.strip())
            
            if matchObject is not None:
                key, value = matchObject.groups()
                dataDict[key] = value
            else:
                raise Exception("Line={}, content=\"{}\" has some formatting issues, regex failed".format(index + 1, line))
            
            if (index + 1) % 5 == 0:
                records.append(dataDict)
                dataDict = OrderedDict() # reset for next iteration
                dataDict["File Name"] = fileName
            
        return records

def convertAllFilesToDataFrame(
        parser = oneFileSingleRecordParser, 
        validParserNames = ("oneFileSingleRecordParser", "oneFileMultiRecordParser",)
    ):
    
    if not parser.__name__ in validParserNames:
        raise Exception("Proper parser was not used")
    
    pathToFiles = getcwd()
    textFilePaths = list(map(lambda path: str(path), Path(pathToFiles).glob("*.txt")))
    
    dataDicts = []
    
    for textFilePath in textFilePaths:
        if parser.__name__ == validParserNames[0]:
            dataDicts.append(parser(textFilePath))
        elif parser.__name__ == validParserNames[1]:
            dataDicts.extend(parser(textFilePath))
    
    dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(dataDicts)
    return dataFrame
```

`convertAllFilesToDataFrame(parser = oneFileMultiRecordParser)` will produce:
[image]

`convertAllFilesToDataFrame(parser = oneFileSingleRecordParser)` will produce:
[image]

The code isn't exactly dry, but you can probably do that with a bit more time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got a TypeError: convertAllFilesToDataFrame() missing 1 required positional argument: 'textFilePathsRoot'.  

I changed it to convertAllFilesToDataFrame("path/to/your/text/file/directory") and I am getting SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing. Still working on it to try and solve it

Comment: in that function, pass in the path to your directory where you have all the text files.

Comment: Got it fixed! Thanks for your help! You just made my job a lot easier now!

Comment: If this is the right answer to your question, consider accepting it as the definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you said that you have one record per file, but many files. Let us assume that you have a *thing* that gives you the names of the files, so that `list(filenames())` is a list containing the relevant filenames.

You should first build a function that builds a dictionary from a filename:

```
fieldnames = ['Yield', 'Timestamp', 'Angle', 'ErrorCode 10', 'ErrorCode 12',
              'ErrorCode 13', 'ErrorCode 20']

def getrecord(filename):
    with open(filename) as fd:
        d = {'FileName': filename}
        for line in fd:
            k, v = [i.strip() for i in line.split(':', 1)]
            if k in fieldnames:
                d[k] = v
        return d
```

You can now build your dataframe with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([getrecord(filename) for filename in filenames()],
                  columns = ['FileName'] + fieldnames)
```